# Executing some simple command in Command prompt using Python

Tags: python, command-prompt

I need to execute the simple command below in windows 7 command prompt using Python26.

```
cd C:\Python26\main project files\Process

C:\Aster\runtime\waster Analysis.comm
```

It runs a FEM simulation and I tried it manually and it worked well. Now, I want to automate the write procedure using Python26.

I studied the other questions and found that the os.system works but it didn't. Also I saw subprocess module but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It would be very helpful to us if you posted some code which shows your attempts.  Then we might be able to understand (and explain to you) *why* your code didn't work.

Comment: Dear Tichodroma; Tnx for your attention. I first used os.system functions as follows:os.startfile("C:\Command prompt") It works well. But when I wanna use os.system("cd C:\Python26\main project files\Process") a cmd window appears and hides quickly and I got return code=1.

Answer (score 2):

The current directory is a process property:  Every single process has its own current directory.  A line like

```
os.system("cd xyz")
```

starts a command interpreter (`cmd.exe` on Windows 7) and execute the `cd` command in this subprocess, not affecting the calling process in any way.  To change the directory of the calling process, you can use `os.chdir()` or the `cwd` keyword parameter to `subprocess.Popen()`.

Example code:

```
p = subproces.Popen(["C:/Aster/runtime/waster", "Analysis.comm"],
                    cwd="C:/Python26/main project files/Process")
p.wait()
```

(Side notes: Use forward slashes in path names in Python files.  You should avoid `os.system()` and passing `shell=True` to the function in the `subprocess` module unless really necessary.)

Comment: Tnx for your quick response;

I tried the code as follows:

os.startfile("C:\Command prompt.lnk")

It works well and a command prompt window appears. Now I want to write the commands pointed at the question.

I tried your solution as follows:

os.system("cd C:\Python26\main project files\Process")

Comment: but I see no change in command prompt window. Also when I try the second solution I get the following error:

>>> p = subprocess.Popen("C:/Aster/runtime/waster Analysis.comm",cwd="C:/Python26/main project files/Process")

Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: File "<pyshell#70>", line 1, in <module>
    p = subprocess.Popen("C:/Aster/runtime/waster Analysis.comm",cwd="C:/Python26/main project files/Process")
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 833, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Please help me in this matter...
Tnx in advance...

Comment: @hadiParvaz: The error message says something like "file not found".  You have a typo in one of your paths.  I can't help you to figure that out.

Comment: Dear Sven, The paths used are completely true. I checked them lots of times and they were completely true. You know the command "C:/Aster/runtime/waster Analysis.comm" executes an analysis and I think that the error comes from that. By the way why the command os.system("C:/Aster/runtime/waster Analysis.comm") doesn't work for this purpose? By execution, a cmd window appears and hides immediately!!!

Comment: @hadiParvaz: No, the error happens within your Python process, not in the subprocess.  You shouldn't be using `os.system()` – it has various problems, one of them being that it passes your string unprocesses to `cmd`, and `cmd` understands neither forward slashes in paths nor unquoted spaces in filenames.  (Note that *when* your are using back slashes in paths, you must use *raw string literals* to make things work correctly.)

Comment: I think that I should have said a point. The command "C:/Aster/runtime/waster Analysis.comm" executes waster that reads Analysis.comm from the directory that has been introduced using "cd C:\Python26\main project files\Process". In another words, we have a file name "Analysis.comm" in the Process directory and waster runs it. It looks like the execution of a python script using command: Python myScript.py... So, we need to have a space in address we type.

Comment: @hadiParvaz: OK, now I understand the setup!  I updated my answer with this new information.  Using a bacth file is certainly not a better way to do this.